# Задача по JS с вызовом строки и на возврат строки

Tags: javascript

Как можно написать функцию, которая будет вызываться следующим образом

```
carMachine('bmv')('Mike')
```

и будет возвращать строку с вопросом про указанную машину- например "bmv"

> Mike, can you consider a BMW as a purchase ?

Comment: ну напиши функцию которая берет в себя 2 аргумента и потом выводите

Comment: @Andrey Freiz Нет, насколько понимаю, здесь все чуть посложнее будет. Если заметили, каждый из аргументов в своих скобках. Т.е. надо написать функцию, возвращающую другую функцию.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это делается:

```
function carMachine(car){
   return (name) => `${name}, can you consider a ${car} as a purchase ? `
}
```